# maven build shows as failing on Github for karate

Tags: karate

It seems the karate project has been updated to the 1.4.1 release. On the GitHub page, I noticed that the Maven build is showing as failing. Not sure if this is related to the latest release, has anyone tried updating to the latest release and seen any issues?

Attached is the screenshot from the Github project page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - we updated the badge as per instructions here and it seems to be back to green: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge